# I accidentally lost the key to my wallet

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key

So I recently formatted my drives again and wiped my hard drives. I mistakenly did not copy my Account key but I copied my password. Is there anyway to gain back my account?

Comment: There are various data recovery tools or services you can use. Otherwise you may be able to recover it if it was generated from a HD wallet using the original seed. Please search on previous questions.

Comment: @o0ragman0o is right. If at all it is HD wallet, if not possibilities to recover is zero.

Comment: suggestion: change your post title to a question: "Is there any way to recover the key to myetherwallet?"

Answer (score 1):

MyEtherWallet is not a "web wallet". You do not create an account or give MEW your ETH or tokens to hold onto. MEW is simply an interface that allows you to interact with the Ethereum blockchain.

For security & privacy reasons, no sensitive data is saved, stored, or transmitted when you use MyEtherWallet. They, like anybody else, only have access to the information that is publicly available on the blockchain.

Unfortunately, that means they cannot:

- Recover your private key
- Access you account
- Recover or reset your password
- Reverse or cancel transactions
- Recover your account
- Send your ETH or Tokens from one address to another

There may be a chance that you saved it without realizing it. So, just in case:

- Do a full search of your computer for “UTC-“ and see if the private key shows up.
- Do a full search of your computer for your address without the 0x at the beginning.
- If you know when you created it, look through all files during that time period for any documents that may hold your key or screenshots.
- Generate a new wallet via https://www.myetherwallet.com/#generate-wallet and take a look and the different options you may have downloaded or saved. Sometimes that can jog your memory.

In the future, it may be prudent to print out a paper version of your wallet and keep it in multiple physical locations.

I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in with your wallet provider? Myetherwallet has a help center, and they address your question (under "I no longer have my private key. What can I do?").  Basically the short of it is unfortunately: nothing (they explain why). https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/help_center

This said, while searching the internet for lost key etherwallet, I found a thread started by someone in a similar situation to yours. Someone else answered: "If you didn't write anything to the disk after your formatted it the data it may still be recoverable." Not sure if that applies in your case, but may be worth a deeper look? https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4o5bje/help_recovering_ether/