# Lost Private key

Tags: private-key, private

I lost my private key and can not access to my account to send coin. I still hold my MEW address. So please help me with this case

Answer (score 0):

Check "[I acccidently lost the key to my wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16785/i-acccidently-lost-the-key-to-my-wallet)". Unfortunately, the short answer is: if it's lost -> Game Over. You can't do anything. It's lost forever.