# How get private key from eth address public key/address

Tags: private-key, cpp-ethereum, public-key

By mistake I send "TRU" erc20 token in a ether address and can't access it now. I have only eth address and public key of this address. How to get private key from eth address or using public key?

I already scan address qr code & add it in my trust-wallet, here show my balance but I can't send it to other address, it's show watch-only address. But If I get private key of this address then I can send my balance from this address.

Is their any way to get private key from public key?
Please help me asap.

Comment: If you were able to restore using an address or public key, everyone would steal everyone's funds. Sorry to say your money is likely gone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I accidentally lost the key to my wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16785/i-accidentally-lost-the-key-to-my-wallet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the private key of an address simply by knowing its public key. Otherwise, anyone could access any address and steal the tokens of this address.

If you sent tokens to an address that you do not own (you do not have the private key), your tokens are lost. You may try to contact the owner of the address and ask them to send you back the token, if you know who the owner is, but that's it.